# multiple file inputs trying to replace the first one with the contents of the second

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

I have the following file uploads

```
<input type="file" name="files2[]" multiple onchange="readURL(this);" size="1" class="input-file" />
```

I need to somehow replace files[] with files2[] when files2 is set.

Here are the contents of (files/files):

```
Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] =>c GIF.gif ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/gif ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpF943.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 9921 ) ) [files2] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 14 beresford.png [1] => combination-boilerc2.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpF944.tmp [1] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpF955.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0
```

I have tried the condition below but this doesn't seem to be met

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files2']['error'][0])) {

$_FILES['files']=$_FILES['files2'];

}
```

If I change this to the following below the condition is always met causing the contents of files[] to be empty as well.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files2'])) { //this is always reached even if files 2 is empty...

    $_FILES['files']=$_FILES['files2'];

    } 

Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) [files2] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) ) 0 is an Invalid file type:
```

*note files and files2 are confusing names for the inputs, clearly aware of that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work :

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files2']['name'][0])) {

    $_FILES['files']=$_FILES['files2'];

    }
```

Not sure if there is a better way to check.